# How to make a login page with Polymer

Tags: php, polymer, material-design, paper-elements

I have made a simple HTML Polymer login page:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>

  <meta name="viewport" 
  content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

  <script src="./components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js">
  </script>

  *All the import*

  *All the style*

</head>

<body unresolved>

    <paper-shadow class="card" z="2">Login ECG Quizz

      <paper-input-decorator label="Mail">
          <input id="Mail" is="core-input" name="Mail"/>
      </paper-input-decorator>

      <paper-input-decorator label="Mots de passe">
          <input id="password" is="core-input" name="j_password" type="password"/>
      </paper-input-decorator>

      <paper-button raised id="register" class="register">S'enregistrer</paper-button>

      <paper-fab mini icon="done" class="button" title="done"></paper-fab>

    </paper-shadow>


<script>
</script>


</body>

</html
```

I've no idea how to send the data and check the data with a simple php script...?

I've read the documentation of core-ajax, but I don't understand it very well...
What is the best practice to make this login without refreshing pages? Can you help me and if possible show me a little example?

I know how to make a simple login page with PHP. But I've no idea of the best practices with Polymer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is a site for specific problems with existing code. Requests for guidelines, tutorials, or "best practices" are typically off-topic here. If you can edit this question to include the PHP log-in page you have, it might get a response. As it stands, however, this question risks being closed.

Comment: Additionally, check out these questions on Polymer and PHP; they may help: [One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842632/polymer-and-php), [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048700/does-polymer-work-in-php-files), [Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244992/php-not-receiving-post-body-set-in-polymer-core-ajax-element).

Answer (score 3):

you can look at my project completely made with polymer, it's in github and here's the URL https://github.com/josestrk/PersonalQR

in the page
https://github.com/josestrk/PersonalQR/blob/master/pages/login-page.html

as you can see i have user_field and password_field and they have some event listeners that onblur or on keydow do some checks, i hope it will be usefull your you ;)

in any case i think you should componentize a little bit more your app, if you read the page and u stilll have no clue comment here and i'll try to make you a little jsbin